# C# how to save userinput in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently trying to make a small program that store the input by the user in the textbox to a file but somehow I couldn't save the input to the file this is what I have done so far:

First Class:

```
class Name
{
    private string SongName;
    private string ArtistName;

    //Constructor
    public Name(string SongName, string ArtistName)
    {
        this.ArtistName = ArtistName;
        this.SongName = SongName;
    }

    //Properties for SongName
    public string songName
    {
        get { return SongName; }
        set { SongName = value; }
    }

    //Properties for ArtistName
    public string artistName
    {
        get { return ArtistName; }
        set { ArtistName = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is the Form1 code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string SongName, ArtistName;

    public void Registry()
    {
        List<Name> MusicList = new List<Name>();
        MusicList.Add(new Name(SongName = txtSongName.Text , ArtistName = txtArtistName.Text)); //Add new elements to the NameClass

        //Save the list
        StreamWriter FileSaving = new StreamWriter("MusicList");
        for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count; i++)
        {
            string sName = MusicList[i].songName;
            string aName = MusicList[i].artistName;
        }
        FileSaving.Close();
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registry();
        //Set the textbox to emty so the user can enter new data
        txtArtistName.Text = "";
        txtSongName.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: your not doing anything with the streamwriter just opening it `filesaving.writeline`

Comment: your code does `NOTHING` also what's up with this line  string sName = MusicList[i].songName;
            string aName = MusicList[i].artistName; you are not writing anything to the file i would also read up on how to use properties..

Comment: Pretty simple issue here if you just look at your code and consider what is missing. Good luck

Comment: Always search for examples, you will learn a great deal. In cases like this you should go line by line and just comment what each line does. This will help you understand what is happening. You would have realized you never commented about anything writing to a file.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you did, but please do not strike out your question content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop you need to actually write the values to the stream.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count i++)
{
    string sName = MusicList[i].songName;
    string aName = MusicList[i].artistName;
    FileSaving.WriteLine(sName + ' ' + aName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

....You never write anything to the file.....

[A quick Google got me this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Notice the call to `file.WriteLine(line);` also...you realize you are not creating your file with an extension, also?

Comment: @JeremyK I hope you are kidding? Being a beginner does not excuse you from knowing how to google.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with you pointing that out. Just saying you are pretty harsh on your tone and I wouldn't be surprised if this person is very very new to programming or even young. Just no need for falling asleep on the . key :)

Comment: And his lack of google skills won't make up for his lack of understanding on programming. His question does not belong here as he clearly needs someone to coach him.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are creating the `StreamWriter` but never using it:

```
StreamWriter FileSaving = new StreamWriter("MusicList");
for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count; i++)
{
    string sName = MusicList[i].songName;
    string aName = MusicList[i].artistName;
}
FileSaving.Close();
```

strings aName and sName are assigned to but never saved.

See example here on using StreamWriter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
        for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(MusicList[i].songName + " , " + MusicList[i].artistName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I my opinion You should use XML Serialization

here is my serialization generic class

```
public static class Serializer<T>
{
    public static T Deserialize(string path)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        System.IO.FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);

            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Serialize(string path, T obj, bool createFolder = false)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        if (createFolder)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        }

        using (System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(path, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            xmlWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented;

            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj);

            xmlWriter.Flush();
            xmlWriter.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in Registy Method

```
    public void Registry()
    {
        List<Name> MusicList = new List<Name>();
        MusicList.Add(new Name(SongName = txtSongName.Text , ArtistName = txtArtistName.Text)); //Add new elements to the NameClass

        Serializer<List<Name>>.Serialize(@"C:\saved.xml", MusicList);
    }
```

**note that you must add default constructor in class Name**